# generating functions (recurrence relations)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, recurrence-relations, generating-functions

how can I use generating functions to solve the recurrence relation $$a_n = 4a_{n-1} -4a_{n-2}$$

$$a_1 = 1, a_2=3$$

some terms: 1,3,8,20,48

$$a_n -4a_{n-1} +4a_{n+2} =0$$

$$f(x)=  1+3x+ 8x^2  +20x^3+\dots$$
$$-4xf(x)=  4x+12x^2 +32x^3$$
$$4x^2f(x)=    4x^2  +12x^3 +32x^4$$

$$(1-4x+4x^2)f(x)=1-x$$

so I get $f(x)=\frac {1-x}{1-4x+4x^2}$ but I think it should be $f(x)= \frac {x-x^2}{1-2x^2}$ dunno where it went wrong.

and then I'm wondering how can I find $a_n$ now that I have the generating function?

Answer (score 3):

Start by setting up your generating function:
$$
F(x):=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n.
$$
Now, using the recurrence relation that $a_n=4a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}$, you can rewrite this as
$$
\begin{align*}
F(x)&=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n\\
&=a_1x+a_2x^2+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}a_nx^n\\
&=a_1x+a_2x^2+\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}(4a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2})x^n\\
&=a_1x+a_2x^2+4x\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}a_{n-1}x^{n-1}-4x^2\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}a_{n-2}x^{n-2}\\
&=a_1x+a_2x^2+4x\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}a_nx^n-4x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_nx^n.
\end{align*}
$$
These last two sums are closely related to your original generating function $F(x)$.  See if you can rewrite this formula by leveraging that fact, to get a functional relation satisfied by $F(x)$; from there, solving for $F(x)$ will give you an explicit generating function for $(a_n)$, and from there an explicit expression for $(a_n)$ itself.

Comment: how can I find F(x) from that?

Comment: You will end up with an equation that looks like $F(x)=\text{(something in terms of $F(x)$)}$. Then, treating $F(x)$ as an unknown quantity, you can solve for $F(x)$ explicitly.

Comment: so what did u get F(x) to be and how??

Comment: I'm not going to give you the answer. You have all the parts you need to get that. Notice that one of the two sums above is exactly $F(x)$, and the other one would be if it wasn't missing one term.