# Solving a homogeneous recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

How to solve $$a_n=4a_{n-1}-4a_{n-2}$$
$a_0=6$ and $a_1=8$

I found first few terms as $$6,8,8,0,...  $$
But I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1544784/42969.

Comment: Many many many questions about homogeneous linear recurrences have been asked and answered here before. Maybe do a little search for something like yours.

Comment: Yes...I should have looked that earlier. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make its characteristic equation: $$x^2-4x+4=0$$
Solving which gives repeated root as $x=2$
So, its solution will be like: $$a_n=(A+Bn)2^n$$
Just substitute for initial conditions and you get $A=6$ and $B=-2$

> So, $$a_n=(6-2n)\cdot2^n$$

Comment: I already got my answer. Thanks omega...